# Live updates between React components based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My *(simplified)* goal:
Show a form input's text content beside the form itself and update the reflected text as the input text changes. The form lives within a React component, and the displayed text lives inside another one.

I can use the component state to control the input's text and change the state based on *onChange* form event. But how can I also change the state of the displayed text so that I get the live updates I'm looking for?

Input and output components have the same parent component.

Here's my input component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function InputBoxTest() {
  const [inText, setInText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setInText(event.target.value);
    // My instinct is to setOutText here, but I can't...
  };

  return (
    <textarea className="form-control" id="comment" onChange={handleChange}>
      {inText}
    </textarea>
  );
}

export default InputBoxTest;
```

My output component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function OutputBoxTest() {
  const [outText, setOutText] = useState("");

  return <p>{outText}</p>;
}

export default OutputBoxTest;
```

And my parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import InputBoxTest from "./InputBoxTest";
import OutputBoxTest from "./OutputBoxTest";

function Test1(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="container-fluid col-sm-7">
          <InputBoxTest />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-5">
          <OutputBoxTest />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Test1;
```

Comment: Define a function in Test1 that receives the text and change the state. Pass that function to InputBoxTest and call it from handleChange. Make OutputBoxTest depend on Test1's state.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with state management with redux. Or mobx if you want to keep things really simple.

Comment: @rodrigoap I've tried this, but get stuck defining the function and passing it. If I define the function inside of the Test1 component, I call Test1.changeState() from handleChange in InputTextTest and get a Type Error: default.changeState is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the State Hook from InputBoxText into the ParentComponent Test1
InputBoxText is then used for displaying and updating the state
OutputBoxText is used for displaying only

```
import React from "react";
import InputBoxTest from "./InputBoxTest";
import OutputBoxTest from "./OutputBoxTest";

function Test1(props) {

   const [inText, setInText] = useState("");
   const handleChange = event => {
       setInText(event.target.value);
   };

   return (
      <>
         <div className="row">
         <div className="container-fluid col-sm-7">
             <InputBoxTest text={inText} handleChange={handleChange}  />
         </div>
         <div className="col-sm-5">
            <OutputBoxTest text={inText}/>
         </div>
        </div>
     </>
   );
}

export default Test1;


function InputBoxTest(props) {
   return (
      <textarea className="form-control" id="comment" onChange={props.handleChange}>
         {props.text}
      </textarea>
   );
}
export default InputBoxTest;


function OutputBoxTest(props) {
   return <p>{props.text}</p>;
}

 export default OutputBoxTest;
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share some state between 2 components, you need to move that state in their (at least first) parent. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Basically what this means is that your `Test1` component should be holder of your `textarea` value.

Please see this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-platform-b83zu) based on your code.

Comment: You can accept the answer if the solution works for you.